# Two default Ubuntu instances cannot access each over through Amazon VPC

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am running two Ubuntu 12.04 instances, both of which cannot access each other.

Machine 1:

```
eth0 - 10.0.0.20
eth1 - 10.0.0.30
```

netstat -nr:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Machine 2:

```
eth0 - 10.0.0.100
eth1 - 10.0.0.40
```

netstat -nr:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

Both machines have access to each other only through internet, but not through VPC (LAN, in other words). Disabling firewall does not help. Machine 1 can ping only 10.0.0.100. Machine 2 can ping only 10.0.0.30. I am unable to connect to any of the machines in TCP/UDP protocols through LAN. There are no ACLs and the daemons on the machines are listening on all IPs, all interfaces. What could be the problem?

**Edit 1:**

It seems that the problem was in routing tables. I have solved the issue on Machine 1 after deleting 1 NIC on Machine 2 and doing some random actions. This resulted in DHCP obtaining these rules:

```
~$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local 
32765:  from 10.0.0.30 lookup 2 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 
~$
```

I cannot reproduce this on Machine 2, but I can add the rules and routing tables manually with:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table 2
ip rule add from 10.0.0.167 lookup 2 prio 1000
```

How could I avoid doing it manually?

Comment: can i ask: why do you have two ip's from same subnet on different interfaces? you can have multiple ip addresses assigned to the same interface.

Comment: As I understand, Amazon does not allow binding more than 2 external IP (Elastic IPs) to one network interface. Am I right? Or should I bind it to local network address and then it would work? But still - shouldn't it work the way I'm trying to make it work?

Comment: Could you please show a traceroute from machine1 to machine2 and vice-versa? But as GioMac already said, your routing tables look messed up because you use the same subnet on multiple interfaces. Doing that may produce the side-effects you encounter.

Comment: If you need that many IPv4 addresses, something is probably wrong with your architecture. (Or you're trying to send spam....)

Comment: I need at least 2 IP addresses because I am running several HTTP servers. If I were sending spam, Amazon wouldn't work (they limit the amount of traffic on 25 port and they are very cautious, meaning that they check bounces and etc. from time to time). By the way - sometimes the ping as well as traffic from machine 2 to 10.0.0.30 goes through and sometimes it doesn't. The traceroutes are in case they don't: http://pastebin.com/CGjmSAR9

Comment: What are the contents of your security groups?

Comment: have a look at ethernet aliases for the proper way to do this.  Also, simplify, test, confirm, then proceed: make sure connectivity works with 1 address per interface per machine first before adding complexity.

Comment: Security groups allow all traffic in all protocols.
Ethernet aliases do not work and this is NOT the proper way to do this in Amazon VPC, because EIP are usually attached to NICs, not private IPs.

P. S. I added some more information by editing. The problem was in the routing tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the routes more specifically. Routing will prefer the first matching route ordered by specificity, metric, then order of addition.

For example, on machine 1, add the following route:

```
ip route add 10.0.0.40/32 dev eth1 src 10.0.0.30
```

And on machine 2:

```
ip route add 10.0.0.30/32 dev eth1 src 10.0.0.40
```

you may want to delete the more general routes for eth1 on both machines:

```
ip route del 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1
```

Since they are in /24s, you should try to get them in different subnets, for example, if both eth1s were in 10.0.1.0/24, you wouldn't have this problem at all.

Comment: Now I get this: http://pastebin.com/NVu36Hiq

Comment: hmm, it's not particularly clear which two are your internal interface pair and which are your external; that should work.

Comment: Both of them are internal and external.